# Hatcher 2.2 Ex17 Show the isomorphism between cellular and singular homology is natural in the following sense.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I have found an answer of Hatcher 2.2 Ex17 on page 11-12 in this file.

[image]

But I'm confused that why filling the mapping $H_n(X)\to H_n(Y)$ with $f_* $ according to the long exact sequence on homology of good pairs, (2) commutes? I can't find the path on the big communitative diagram corresponding to $i_Y\circ f_* $ on (2).

Very Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I had no issues understanding the post without reading the title. I did, however, have to click the link and read the PDF. Which is also suboptimal.

Comment: Now I have enough reputation to post the picture lol.

Comment: You should still include the link: providing someone else's work without proper acknowledgment is plagiarism.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with good pairs.

We have a cellular map $f : X \to Y$. In particular $f(X^n) \subset Y^n$ and $f(X^{n-1}) \subset Y^{n-1}$.  This gives the following commutative diagram:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
X^n @>{j}>> X \\
@V{f}VV @VV{f}V \\
Y^n @>>{j}> Y \end{CD}
Application of $H_n$ gives the commutative diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
H_n(X^n) @>{}>> H_n(X) \\
@V{f_*}VV @VV{f_*}V \\
H_n(Y^n) @>>{}> H_n(Y) \end{CD}
Moreover the boundary operators $\partial : H_{n+1}(X,A) \to H_n(A)$ are natural with respect to induced maps. This means that if $f : (X,A) \to (Y,B)$ is a map of pairs, then we get the following commutative diagram:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
H_{n+1}(X,A) @>{\partial}>> H_n(A)\\
@V{f_*}VV @VV{f_*}V \\
H_{n+1}(Y,B) @>>{\partial}> H_n(B) \end{CD}

Apply this to $(X,A) = (X^n,X^{n-1})$ and $(Y,B) = (Y^n,Y^{n-1})$. Combining the last two diagrams shows that $?  = f_*$ does the job.